# Union all query - need latest date per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with SQL.

I got 2 tables (`T1` and `T2`), made it into 1 table (`T3`) by using `union all`

```
T1
DateT               GROUP ID_Pers   Sec
2016/10/24 13:05:33 840   122       7.75
2016/10/24 11:10:29 840   244       8.4

T2
DateT               GROUP ID_Pers   Sec
2016/10/24 12:10:37 840   122       7.75
2016/10/25 08:38:59 840   156       7
2016/10/25 09:39:22 840   244       6.7

T3
DateT               GROUP ID_Pers   Sec
2016/10/24 13:05:33 840   122       7.75
2016/10/24 11:10:29 840   244       8.4
2016/10/24 12:10:37 840   122       7.75
2016/10/25 08:38:59 840   156       7
2016/10/25 09:39:22 840   244       6.7
```

I use this to do it:

```
SELECT  DateT,GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec
FROM
    (
        SELECT DateT,GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateT,GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T2
    ) T3
GROUP   BY ID
```

Now I want to add a query to this union all to get the lastest `DateT`, per `Group`, per `IDPers`, `Sec`

Result should be like this:

```
DateT               GROUP ID_Pers   Sec
2016/10/24 13:05:33 840   122       7.75
2016/10/25 09:39:22 840   244       6.7
2016/10/25 08:38:59 840   156       7
```

## Any suggestions?

Hi,
still not working, when i use:

1. SELECT GROUPN, ID_Pers, MAX(DateT) as DateT,  Sec FROM
           (
               SELECT DateT,GROUPN, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT DateT,GROUPN, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T2
           ) T3 GROUP   BY ID_Pers, GROUPN, Sec

I get result :
GROUP ID_PERS DateT         Sec
840 122 2016/10/24 13:05:33 7.75
840 156 2016/10/25 8:38:59  7
840 244 2016/10/25 9:39:22  6.7
840 244 2016/10/24 11:10:29 8.4

Double result for ID_Pers 244. Should only show one result for 244.

Result should be
GROUP ID_PERS DateT         Sec
840 122 2016/10/24 13:05:33 7.75
840 156 2016/10/25 8:38:59  7
840 244 2016/10/25 9:39:22  6.7

Only one result for each group and latest date.

Comment: `SELECT  max(DateT),GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec......group by GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec`

Comment: @artm put as answer, better than the others as it's short and sweet

Comment: @Edward, answer not working still having problem

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this query below. It will return the result as your expected.

```
SELECT GROUP, ID_Pers, MAX(DateT) as DateT, MIN(Sec) as Sec
FROM
        (
            SELECT DateT,GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DateT,GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T2
        ) T3
GROUP   BY ID_Pers, GROUP
```

Comment: Hi, is this possible without MIN(SEC)?

Comment: @Frankie: It's impossible. Because you want group by 2 fields ID_Pers and GROUP. You can use MAX or AVG(Sec), or remove this field if is not necessary, my friend.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this without Min(sec), cause Min(sec) will affect the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `GROUP BY`, I think you want `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT DateT, GROUP, ID_Pers, Sec
FROM (SELECT DateT, GROUP, ID_Pers, Sec,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP, ID_Person ORDER BY DateT DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ((SELECT DateT,GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T1
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT DateT,GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T2
            )
           ) T3
    ) T3
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cteDate(DateT, GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec)
AS
(
SELECT DateT,GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT DateT,GROUP, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T2
)

SELECT *
FROM cteDate x
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT  MAX(DateT) MaxDateT,GROUP, ID_Pers
                FROM cteDate
                GROUP BY GROUP, ID_Pers
                ) temp
        ON temp.MaxDateT =  x.DateT AND temp.GROUP = x.GROUP AND temp.ID_Pers = x.ID_Pers
```

Comment: how do I use this in combination with my union all query?  SELECT GROUPN, ID_Pers, MAX(DateT) as DateT, Sec FROM ( SELECT DateT,GROUPN, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T1 UNION ALL SELECT DateT,GROUPN, ID_Pers,Sec FROM T2 ) T3 GROUP BY ID_Pers, GROUPN, Sec

Answer (score 0):

[image]I think it may help you

[image]

```
;WITH 
  cteTotalSales (Datet,GROUPx,ID_Pers,Sec)
  AS
  (
select Datet,GROUPx,ID_Pers,Sec from t1
union
select Datet,GROUPx,ID_Pers,Sec from t2
)
select Datet,GROUPx,ID_Pers,Sec from cteTotalSales
where Datet in (select max(Datet) from cteTotalSales group by GROUPx,ID_Pers)
```

Comment: Can only use union, cannot create new table. Any ideas?

Comment: Outcome should be: 244 2016/10/25 9:39:22 6.7   
156 2016/10/25 8:38:59 7
122 2016/10/24 13:05:33 7.75

Comment: ;WITH 
  cteTotalSales (Datet,GROUPx,ID_Pers,Sec)
  AS
  (
select Datet,GROUPx,ID_Pers,Sec from t1
union
select Datet,GROUPx,ID_Pers,Sec from t2
)
select Datet,GROUPx,ID_Pers,Sec from cteTotalSales
where Datet in (select max(Datet) from cteTotalSales group by GROUPx,ID_Pers) order by Datet desc

Comment: Cte-Common table Expression,It is not a new table.